# Ionic 2: How to add Class from Controller

Tags: angular, ionic2

How to add dynamic Class to `BODY` from Controller in Ionic 2?
My code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'pages.html'
})
export class PagesPage {

  constructor() {

  }

  addClass() {

    //This ADD CLASS in tag BODY

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In angular 2 we use references to get elements.

```
<div #reference_id></div>
```

add extra imports

```
import {ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
```

in class

```
 export class App implements AfterViewInit{
    @ViewChild('reference_id') elem:ElementRef;
    constructor(private rd: Renderer2) {}
    ngAfterViewInit() {
          console.log(this.rd); 
          console.log(this.elem.nativeElement);
          this.rd.addClass(this.elem.nativeElement, 'new_class_name'); // this adds the class 
    }
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Here working [plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/y8iFYDjtaXCIaoaWN0pB?p=preview)

Inspect element i.e., **Hello** in the plunker result to check added class i.e., **new_class**

Comment: Updated answer to get element

Comment: Now i have error: 'Declaration expected.' in string @ViewChild('.app-root') elem:ElementRef;